# Is there a way to allow multiple responses per Slack channel for a form sent through Workflow Builder?

Tags: slack

I've set up a workflow (with Slack Workflow Builder) to send a survey to a channel, asking for feedback. I want everyone to be able to answer it, but as soon as one person responds the workflow completes.

Going back to the setup I see the message "If you send this form to a channel, keep in mind that only one person can click the button to submit a response."

If I can't send to more than one person at a time, and I can't get multiple people in a channel to respond, is there any other workaround I could try?

Comment: did you figure something out? Facing the same issue - avoiding having to duplicate for each person

Comment: No I didn't unfortunately - or at least not without using a tool like Zapier.

Comment: I'm using it for daily / weekly standups so with a team of ~10 it's bearable to duplicate - resorted to that

Comment: The worst part about this is that it says "Download responses" and "Send submitted responses to a channel or to someone in a DM" ...  these are both plural! it should say, "response" in the singular because it can never have more than one. Extremely disappointing to be honest. I guess I'll try adding every member of the team, but the intention was to have the message posted to the channel, not sliding into DMs.

Comment: 8 months on, and I am still searching for an answer to this. :/

Comment: Just when I was finally happy that the workflow will work for 30-plus people, Slack threw a curveball. Extremely disappointing.

Comment: also looking for a solution to this...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it up through a Google form that feeds through Slack, and feeds the responses back to a spreadsheet. I've done this before successfully

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.